# Where can I download Visual Studio 2012 RC and Windows 8 Customer Preview?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

I've heard that VS2012 beta and Windows 8 Customer Preview will be available for download today (29 II 2012) but I cannot find any links to them. Does anybody know where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct. Windows 8 Customer Preview and Visual Studio 11 (Visual Studio 11, not 2012) will be released today, the 29th.

When it is released, I'm pretty sure it will be available on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa718325

Nobody knows the exact time it will be released though.

Comment: well, the naming is correct, the name Visual Studio 2012 is correct.

Comment: Can you provide an official link that confirms that? I can only find links about VS11. http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/visual-studio-11

Comment: http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/Visual-Studio-11-Not-2011.aspx

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 naming MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd831853(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Looks like it's going to be the 31st of May :) http://www.eweek.com/c/a/Windows/Windows-8-Release-Preview-Due-May-31-Report-149990/

Answer (score 3):

**Download links for Visual Studio 2012 RC All Versions (ISO)**

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247147

Visual Studio 2012 Premium:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247144

Visual Studio 2012 Professional:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247141

Visual Studio 2012 Test Professional:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=247152

Visual Studio 2012 Express For windows 8:
http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810160

note: these links taken from
http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-visual-studio-2012-release-candidate-launched

**Download links for Windows 8 Release Preview (ISO)**

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/iso (x86/x64)